# Thrift publish subscribe

Tags: rpc, publish-subscribe, thrift

I'm evaluating thrift as an rpc framework. I want to be able to do publish/subscribe logic with thrift and was wondering how to do this.

A few different answers may help:

1. Is there a canonical way to do publish/subscribe with thrift?
2. Is there a way to stream results of a call (similar to zerorpc streaming)?
3. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done my own research and it looks like that with thrift, you should serialize and do pub sub over some type of message queue like zeromq or redis.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at DDS?  Data Distribution Service is a full standard for doing publish / subscribe communications via topics.